# Creating a canvas in JavaScript based on variables (with p5.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I want to draw a simple canvas based on variables.

It works like this:

```
function setup() {
   createCanvas(600, 600);
   background(50);
}
```

Why does that not work? (a small canvas, definitely not 600x600 is displayed):

```
var height = 600;
var width = 600;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(height, width);
    background(50)
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: when are you calling `setup()`. and how do you know it doesn't work? Do you get an error? what is the error?

Comment: @lbu it is just drawing a small canvas... (definitely lower than 600x600)

Comment: @Ibu with the P5.js library setup is called automatically

Comment: @Hannes.T just name the variables something else, see my answer for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt work because `height` and `width` are built-in p5 variable names. Try renaming them to something else.

```js
var a = 600;
var b = 600;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(a, b);
    background(50)
}
```

If you are looking to make the canvas the size of the window, you should use `windowWidth` and `windowHeight`.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

To resize the canvas after setup you should do something like this:

```js
var c;

function setup() {
  c = createCanvas(windowWidth-20, windowHeight-20);
}

function draw() {
  background(30);
}

function mousePressed() {
    c.size(windowWidth-20, windowHeight-20);
    console.log(width + " " + height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i have learnt for p5.js Library, I do believe that the `width` and `height` variable are dedicated to the canvas created by the `createCanvas()` and are systems variable, and renaming those variable would most likely solve the problem.