# How to make camera follow an objects in p5.play

Tags: javascript, canvas, camera, p5.play

I'm making a basic shooter game using p5.play, ad i'm getting an error while making the camera follow an object.when i set camera to follow an object, if i have created a canvas, it does not work. but when i tried without making any canvas, it worked correctly.
i don't know why this is happening, but i need to make a canvas to set the size of the  canvas(...duh)

How can i fix it?

here is my code

```
//variables
var player1;
var gun1;
var gun2;

function preload(){
 crosshair = loadImage("cROSSHAIR 2.png")
 
}

function setup(){
    //creating sprites
    player1 = createSprite(400,400,30,30)
    gun = createSprite(player1.x,player1.y-20,5,30)
    gun.shapeColor = "black"
    obj1 =createSprite(200,200,20,20)
    obj3 = createSprite(300,500,20,50)
   
}

function draw(){
  canvas = createCanvas(displayWidth,displayHeight-115)// if i dont create canvas, it works
   background("#32CD32");
   cursor('crosshair')
   gun.x = player1.x;
   gun.y = player1.y-15;

   // functions to move
   //up
  if(keyDown("up")){
    player1.y = player1.y - 5;
  }
  //down
  if(keyDown("down")){
    player1.y = player1.y + 5;
  }
  //right
  if(keyDown("right")){
    player1.x = player1.x + 5;
  }
  //left
  if(keyDown("left")){
    player1.x = player1.x - 5;
  }
  //rotate player sprite towards mouse
  let a = atan2(mouseY - player1.y, mouseX - player1.x);
push()
 angleMode(DEGREES)
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  player1.rotation = a;
pop()
//camera follows player
 camera.position.x = player1.x
 camera.position.y = player1.y

drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with p5, but is the `createCanvas` function supposed to be run within the `setup` function instead? Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944210/creating-a-canvas-in-javascript-based-on-variables-with-p5-js)

Comment: ohh yeah i forgot about that :P

Comment: Just for anyone else that sees this question, did that end up resolving the problem?

Comment: yep that did!  but i want to rotate the player towards the mouse too, and when i put the createCanvas() function in the setup function, the rotation does not work correctly... what could be causing this problem?

Comment: @Chase Ingebritson  what could be causing the problem?